# C++ yet another memory leak issue

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

If I have the following class:

```
class SimpleContainer {
private:
    std::vector<int> vec_;

public:
    void set_vec(std::vector<int>* vec) { 
        vec_ = *vec;
    }

    SimpleContainer(){}
    ~SimpleContainer(){}
};
```

And then do something like:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int>* vec = new std::vector<int>();
    SimpleContainer* sc = new SimpleContainer();
    sc->set_vec(vec);

    delete sc;
}
```

Does vec get leaked? Or does it automatically get cleaned up by the destructor of SimpleContainer? Assume I only call set_vec once.

Comment: Yes. You're making a copy when you `vec_ = *vec`, so the original still gets leaked.

Comment: Why are you managing dynamically allocated memory yourself, and complain about leaks? Use what's provided by the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Answer (score 4):

> Does vec get leaked?

Yes. There are zero calls to `delete` in your code (for a `vector<int>*`). Every `new` needs to be paired with a `delete`.

There is actually no reason to have any pointers here whatsoever. The same behavior could be accomplished with:

```
void set_vec(const std::vector<int>& vec) { 
    vec_ = vec;
}

SimpleContainer sc;
sec.set_vec({});
```